# how do i use libraries on chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i have trying for total of 10h to implement this and i cant make it work
script.js

```
// Create a button element
const button = document.createElement('button');
button.textContent = 'copy';

button.addEventListener('click', () => {

    if(document.getElementsByClassName("product-barcode")){
        const makats = document.getElementsByClassName("product-barcode");
        var makatstring = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < makats.length; i++) {
            makatstring[i] = makats[i].innerText.split(':')[1];
            
        }       
    }
    makatstring = makatstring.join('\n');
    alert(makatstring)

  navigator.clipboard.writeText(makatstring);
});


//button.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
//  button.style.backgroundColor = "#f79e55";
//});


//button.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
//  button.style.backgroundColor = "#f58221";
//});
const myDiv = document.querySelector(".topText");




button.style.fontSize = "20px";
button.style.backgroundColor = "#f58221";
button.style.color = "white";



myDiv.appendChild(button);


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  const locetion = document.querySelector("#app > div:nth-child(1) > div.row > div.col-12.col-md-4 > div.pull-left.d-none.d-md-block");
  var div = document.createElement('div'); 
  div.innerHTML = '<input type="search" id="mySearch" placeholder="Search for something..">';

  let btn = document.createElement("button");
  btn.onclick = function () {
    alert("Button is clicked");
  };
  btn.innerHTML = "Save";
  btn.setAttribute('id','123123')
  locetion.append(div);
  locetion.append(btn);
});

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  const locetionbarcod = document.querySelector("#site-wrappah > div > div.topText");
  var divqrcode = document.createElement('div'); 
  divqrcode.innerHTML = '<svg id="barcode"></svg>';
  //locetionbarcod.append(divqrcode);
  jsBarcode("#barcode", "Hi world!");
  document.body.appendChild(divqrcode)
  generatecode();
});

function generatecode(){
    alert("func work");
}
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "tempname", 
    "description": "tempname", 
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3, 
    "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "contextMenus"],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'",

    "background": {
        "service_worker": "barcoddjs.js"
    },

    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }, 
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["https://www.ivory.co.il/*"],
            "js": ["script.js", "barcoddjs.js"]
        }
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources":[
    {
      "resources": ["barcoddjs.js"],
      "matches": [ "https://www.ivory.co.il/*" ]
    }]
    
}
```

barcoddjs.js is the JsBarcode library for barcodes (just rename it idk why)

for 4 days i am trying to inject barcode to website html so when user print offer something there will be easy way to transfer it the computer

ps if you have improvment to the code it will be great

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample using JsBarcode in a content script.

[image]

manifest.json

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "hoge",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "JsBarcode.all.min.js",
        "content.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

content.js

```js
const img = document.createElement("img");
img.id = "barcode";

const button = document.createElement("button");
button.innerText = "button";

button.onclick = () => {
  JsBarcode("#barcode", "Hi!");
}

document.body.insertBefore(button, document.body.children[0]);
document.body.insertBefore(img, document.body.children[0]);
```